# Cypher sort by amount of same relationship?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I `match` using Cypher by any relation amount? For example, in a database there are `Person`. If this person has any son, they will be related by the relation `[:SON]`.

This query will return each `Person` that has a son:

```
match (p:Person)-[:SON]->(:Person)
return p
```

Knowing this, how can I `match` the number of `Person` that **only has 2 sons**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use size() in the where clause, like so:

```
match (p:Person) where size((p)-[:SON]->())=2 return p
```

Comment: Yes, the `SIZE((n)-[:Foo]->())` pattern is very efficient, since it does not actually require a DB search for the pattern. It leverages the degreeness stats that Neo4j automatically maintains.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `count` function to get the count of sons for each person. Then filter out the persons based on the count.

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:SON]->(:Person)
WITH p, count(r) as sons 
WHERE sons=2
RETURN p
```